# Multi robot exploration

Tags: mobile-robot

I am implementing 2d slam for multi-robot exploration for my university project using GMapping package of a ROS and vrep sofrware. But I also have to implement the following three algorithms in addition to Gmapping:

1. k means algorirhm
2. Hungarian algorithm
3. A* path planning algorithm

Is it possible to implement the above 3 algorithms with Gmapping in ROS?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Saad, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Also, adding salutaions, sign offs and 'thanks' sections to a question is not required, we all tend to be thankful for the people helping us, and expect other people to be thankful too, so saying it just adds noise to the question and distracts people from the problem posed. It may seem counter intuitive, but excessive politeness can itself be impolite, as giving people extra text to read, even if they ignore it, is disrespectful of their time.